# Labels do not disappear

Tags: vba, ms-access

On a report I have a grouptxt.
On opening I'm trying to manipulate some labels.
When Rit = 0 then the labels and txt should be true or false (see below).
But it doesn't work.

```vb
Private Sub Groepskoptekst1_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me.Rit = 0 Or IsNull(Me.Rit) Then
        Me.lblDatum.Visible = True
        Me.Datum.Visible = True
        Me.Rit.Visible = False
        Me.lblRit.Visible = False
        Me.GeenRit.Visible = True
        Me.Traject.Visible = False
        Me.lblKm.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.lblDatum.Visible = True
        Me.Datum.Visible = True
        Me.Rit.Visible = True
        Me.lblRit.Visible = True
        Me.GeenRit.Visible = False
        Me.Traject.Visible = True
        Me.lblKm.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you open Report view or Print preview? Section `Format` events only run in Print views.

Comment: @Andre https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Section.OnFormat says event will fire ` for previewing or printing`

Comment: I open report in Report View. So this won't work. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Adri Move the code to `On Load` event

Comment: Thank you krish KM. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section Format events only run in Print or Print Preview views. – Andre

If you are opening the report in Report View you will want to move your code to the `On Load` event.